# Laravel Error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "?"

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by, prepared-statement, query-builder

No matter how I restructure the route, I keep getting this error from the function: 
(2/2) QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "?": syntax error (SQL: select * from product order by manufacturer asc).

The code I am using is the following:

```
 function get_sort($type,$sort){
       $sql = "select * from product order by ? ?";
       $products = DB::select($sql,array($type,$sort));
       return $products;
   }
```

Please see an image attached of the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.[image]

Comment: Just curious, why not use eloquent? Why use the raw DB class? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-models Possibly add a query scope to the model: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: @developernator how would a query scope be useful in this context?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build a reusable query for that model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bind keywords and columns in prepared statements.  It's probably best to use some sort of whitelist instead.

```
   $columns = ['id', 'name', 'price'];

   $type = in_array($type, $columns) ? $type : 'name';
   $sort = $sort === 'DESC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

   $sql = "select * from product order by $type $sort";
```